# How to get count of agents used in the YAML azure pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, tfs, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

Below is my YAML code, and I have a variable named $(count) in my main YAML file. I want to determine the number of agents required by my pipeline.

Our pipelines only contain agent-based jobs (with and without strategy.parallel).

I am accepting all my stages as parameters, allowing me to parse all the jobs and obtain the count of agents required.

What can I write in the commented code to solve this?

I want to get the Agents Count = (Total of Strategy.parallel values provided in agent based jobs) + (If Strategy.parallel is not provided then consider it as 1)

```
parameters:

- name: stages
  type: stageList
  default: []

stages:

- ${{ each stage in parameters.stages }}:
  - ${{ each job in stage.jobs }}:
    - ${{ if ne(job.pool.name, 'server') }}:
      - ${{ if ne(job.strategy.parallel, '') }}:
              # Add value of ${{ strategy.parallel }} to variable $(count)
      - ${{ else }}:
              # increment $(count) by 1
```

Comment: Hi @owesom, may i know if there's any update? Count agent number with `each` loop in template could be hard to achieve as value needs to shared between different job or stages. You can follow the answer below to try the rest api instead, it works. Let me know if you have any queries.

Comment: Thanks! I need the total count of agents within the first job of my pipeline so that I can use it as a parameter or variable in the pipeline. Shouldn't it be possible to calculate the count from the YAML, since it only includes agent-based jobs..  ?

Answer (score 0):

We can get the agent number in current job. However, since there could be different `stages/jobs` in the pipeline, we cannot easily pass the value to next job and then calculate them all.

You can use rest api [Timeline - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/timeline/get?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1) at `last` job, and parse the job to get the agent numbers in the whole pipeline instead.

Main yaml as below, also added agentless job.

```
trigger: none

stages:
- template: template.yml  # Template reference
  parameters:
    stages:
    - stage: Build
      jobs:
      - job: BuildJob
        steps:
        - script: echo Building!
    - stage: Test
      jobs:
      - job: TestOnWindows
        steps:
        - script: echo Testing on Windows!
      - job: TestOnLinux
        strategy:
          parallel: 4
        steps:
        - script: echo Testing on Linux!
      - job: agentlessjob
        pool: server
        steps:
        - task: Delay@1
          displayName: 'Delay by 1 minutes'
          inputs:
            delayForMinutes: 1

    - stage: Deploy
      jobs:
      - job: Deploy
        steps:
        - script: echo Deploying the code!
        - powershell: |
            $url = "$(System.CollectionUri)$(System.TeamProjectId)/_apis/build/builds/$(Build.BuildId)/timeline?api-version=7.1-preview.2"
            Write-Host "URL: $url"
            $header = @{Authorization = "Bearer $(System.AccessToken)"}
            
            # Send the GET request
            $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Get -Headers $header

            # Filter the records where type is 'Job' and workerName is not null, then calculate the count
            $jobsCount = ($response.records | Where-Object { $_.type -eq 'Job' -and $_.workerName -ne $null }).Count

            # Output the number of jobs
            Write-Output "Number of jobs in the pipeline: $jobsCount"
```

Template.yml content:

```
parameters:
- name: stages  # List of stages
  type: stageList

stages: ${{ parameters.stages }}
```

Pipeline result, it can get result 7 which is correct on my side:

[image]

Comment: This works when count job is at the end, but it doesn't work if you execute the count job as the first one.

Comment: You need to count the jobs/agent at the end since it could happen that one of the jobs is canceled, failed or excluded which will cause the job count to be different in your pipeline. In addition, even with `each` as you did in template(although it's hard to achieve), it still counts the job at the end of the pipeline as it needs to go through each job.